# Databound DataGridView

Tags: winforms, datagridview, datasource, rows

I have a databound DataGridView(DGV).
I need to add new Rows to my DGV on the go (if possible).
Therefore I set the properties: `AllowUserToAddRows` to true and `EditMode` to *EditOnEnter*. And it worked. [Before manually setting the Datasource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMfh5.png)
Until i wanted to display values from my DB in the DGV.
Therfore the Datasource is set manually like this:

```
grdOldName.DataSource = _oldNames; //a List of values
```

Afterwards no new Rows can be added.
[After manually setting the Datasource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ubt0.png)
Is there some awesome way to still add Rows like before?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why don't you let the user still add new rows after your own data is loaded? (`AllowUserToAddRows`)

Comment: The 'AllowUserToAddRows' Value does not change. It is still true.

Comment: `_oldNames; //a List of values`: what does *a List of values* represent here? A `List<something>`? You can use a DataTable, a `BindingList<something>` a BindingSource connected to either of those. Use the latter in case you need to bind other control to the same DataSource.

Comment: `_oldNames` is a list of a custom entity named NameHistory. It has 3 string properties and Guids which are the values displayed in the databound DGV. I am using `BindingList<NameHistory>(DbValues)` to set my Datasource. What is the latter?

Comment: From my understanding there are two requirements in order for the user to add new rows to the grid using a `List<T>`. 1) Use a `BindingList<T>` or `BindingSource` **2) the Class `NameHistory ` MUST have a parameterless  constructor, in your case something like… `public NameHistory() {}`**

Comment: @JohnG Thank you sooooo much! This was indeed the solution. I was using `BindingListView<NameHistory>` not BindingList<> and I also had no empty constructor. Thank you so much!